# Why can the current be written as $I_{in}=I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, conductors, boundary-conditions

An air coaxial transmission line has a solid inner conductor of radius $a$ and an outer conductor of inner radius $b$ and outer radius $c$.Find the $\vec B$ as a functions of radial distance $r$

[image]

We only consider the range of $b<r<c$,because i can't understand the equation which  is written by the book

$Bl=\mu_0I_{in},I_{in}=I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}$,so $\vec B=\vec u_{\phi}\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}\frac{c^2-r^2}{c^2-b^2}$

My question is that why is $I_{in}=I-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^2-b^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying Ampere's law circuital law $I_{\mathcal L}= \oint_{\mathcal L} \mathbf H \cdot d\ell$ you must include in the current $I_{\mathcal L}$ only the currents that are enclosed by the contour ${\mathcal L}$ *inside*. In your question the contour encloses the inner and a *part* of the *outer* sheath that is *within* the circular contour of radius $r>b$. Since the inner core carry the full current, $I$, and the current is uniformly distributed in the metal, the amount of current in the outer sheath that falls *within* the contour is proportional to the enclosed conductor area, that is $-I\frac{r^2-b^2}{c^-b^2}$. The sum of the two is the enclosed current.

Now, as a bonus problem, calculate the field in the inner core, $r<a$.